# The printf result is unexpected

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have the following code:

```
char *buff = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*120);
char *ts_t = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*80);

/*Generating invalid test case for timestamp.*/
printf("Out side of ts.\n");

 while(fgets (ts_t, 80, fp_ts)!=NULL) 
 {
      printf("Inside ts.\n");
      //ts_t[strlen(ts_t)-1] = '\0';
      memset(buff,0,120);       
      memcpy(buff,ts_t,strlen(ts_t)-1);

      printf("The ts is :%s",buff);

      fprintf(fp_test_case,"%s\t%s\t%s%d\t%s\t%s\t%s%04d\n",buff,ver,txn,digit_generate(num),aspid,uid,"Test",count_testCase);

      print_description( fp_description,ts_t,count_testCase,"TimeStamp");
      count_testCase++;
    }

printf("Invalid Time stamp case generated.\n");
```

What is expected is:

**Out side of ts.

Inside ts.

The ts is :05-26-2015T13:53:33.509

Inside ts.

The ts is :05-26-2015T13:53:33.509**

But It is printing as:

**Out side of ts

Inside ts.

Inside ts.

Inside ts.:05-26-2015T13:53:33.509

Inside ts.:2015-26-05T13:53:33.509**

What I have done wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: do not cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your file has DOS-style newlines ("\r\n") but you're running the code on a system that uses *nix-style newlines ("\n"). The extra CR is moving the terminal cursor back to the first column and then the other line is being printed. Either strip the CR from the line or open the file in a mode that can handle the alternate newline style.

Comment: But the problem is the words "The ts is" is completely omitted from second printf. Why I don't know.

Comment: No it isn't. It's obscured by the next printf. Read the second sentence of my answer again.

Comment: Thanks sir!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It was the same issue pointed by you. The file opened in made on windows and used on linux.

Answer (score 1):

Input file has `\r\n` line endings, yet file is opened in binary or in Unix text mode.  See also [@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30086853/2410359)

Rather than `memset(buff,0,120); memcpy(buff,ts_t,strlen(ts_t)-1);`, drop `buff` and use below to get rid of potential `\r` and `\n` regardless of how file was opened.

```
ts_t[strcspn(ts_t, "\r\n")] = `\0`;  // to get rid of potential `\r` and `\n`.
```